# Is it safe to run complete website in react native web view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, security, webview, progressive-web-apps

i have a low budget client who's wants to create an App i have two options

1. PWA - (Progressive Web Apps)
2. RNWebView - (Run application on react native web view)

   Meanwhile using second approach will give me more control over the web app , i can do multiple extra stuff in react native to improve experience then PWA

but my concern is by doing this is it safe to do that way?
like i have a e-com website (which include payment and other permissions as well)
is it good to run complate website on a webView
i have create a blank react native project and just added webView in app.js file and its done seems working but i am concerned about its security and other hacking attacks like JS injection etc...
need help!

here is the code that i have added

```
function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const backgroundStyle = { backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter, flex: 1};

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <WebView
        renderFlag={true}
        useWebKit
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        javaScriptEnabled
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid
        scalesPageToFit
        style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}}
        renderLoading={() => (
          <Text style={{flex: 1, position: 'absolute'}}>Loading WorkS</Text>
        )}
        startInLoadingState
        source={{
          uri: `https://example.com/`,
        }}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

i try to do multiple RnD on that and found that there might be concern about user file system
its device info etc...
hacker can track user's mobile or any info or inject extarnal js init
XSS attack , CSRF attack etc..